# Horseman/PhantomJS - How to check for errors and prevent creating cookies?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, node-horseman

I'm using `node-horseman` on a project that creates RSS Alerts on Google Alerts. The user that hasn't connected yet must log-in with his/her Google account through our application, to then be able to retrieve the feed list (s)he has. The application is basically used to auto-post on Facebook Pages news about any RSS feed created.

So far, the `login` function is the following:

```
* login() {
  if (!this.email || !this.password) {
    this.addError(HTTPResponse.STATUS_FORBIDDEN, 'E-mail and Password are necessary')

    return false
  }

  const horseman = new Horseman({ cookiesFile })

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    horseman
      .open('https://accounts.google.com')
      .type('input[type="email"]', this.email)
      .click('#next')
      .wait(1000)
      .type('input[type="password"]', this.password)
      .click('#signIn')
      .wait(3000)
      .close()

    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(true)
    }, 3000)
  })
}
```

Very simple. It logs in and create a `cookiesFile` to be able to create new feeds and retrieve the existing ones. But it's totally not fail proof since there's no way to check for errors, and I couldn't find an example or make anything wok. I tried to use `evaluate()` and check if there's the  `.error_msg` tag, but it throws an error in the phantomJS `Unhandled rejection fn`:

```
...
.wait(1000)
.evaluate(function() {
  if (jQuery('.error-msg').length > 0) {
    this.addError(HTTPResponse.STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'Error!')
    return false
  }
})
...
```

It doesn't throw any errors not interrupts the execution and still creates a bad cookies file.

Comment: What is this method `this.addError` ? It's not a method of your node.js app, is it?

Comment: This method is in my project to store errors and show tem in the UI. The operation class extends a base operation that has this method.

Comment: Do you know how to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with PhantomJS-like libraries it's very important to get the concept of two main different contexts: one is the context of the script (which you write to automate dealing with a target site) and the other is the context of the target site's **page**. These contexts to do not intersect, they have different variables and capabilities.

Everything that happens inside of `page.evaluate()`, happens in the context of *a browser page*. You can actually visualise that code as being executed in console of your (Chrome|Firefox|Safari) browser at that site.

You can execute this in console at Google login page

```
if (jQuery('.error-msg').length > 0) {
   // ...
}
```

But when you write

```
  if (jQuery('.error-msg').length > 0) {
    this.addError(HTTPResponse.STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 'Error!')
    return false
  }
```

it will throw an error, because you've mixed the two contexts. There is no `.addError` method on that Google page, it's in your script context.

Instead you could write

```
.evaluate(function() {
  if (jQuery('.error-msg').length > 0) {
    return { 
      errors : jQuery('.error-msg').length,
      message : "Some message about errors"
    }
  }
})
.then(function(result){
  if(result.errors > 0)
  {
     // ...
  }
})
```

See the docs on using evaluate in Horseman: https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2

Comment: Personally I find it hard to trust such constructs: `.click('#signIn').wait(3000).close()` What if 3 seconds are not enough? What if the target site changes field names and/or adds new fields? In PhantomJS there's onLoadFinished callback that is called every time a page is done loading - this way one can check if user, for example, logged in or was rejected.

Comment: It did help me, but this horseman is complicated because thing that should work, doesn't work. I do not know how to return to my controller any error message, it keeps showing errors... despicable.

Comment: Well, if the answer *did* help you, why not upvote and accept? I spent time writing it for you :) As for horseman... it is handy for some simple tasks and for integration testing where you control envirionment 100%, but for complicated scraping I'd go with something more low-level, like raw PhantomJS or [node-phantom-simple](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-phantom-simple).

Comment: Sure. Done! Haha.